# Financial education: problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, integers

Mr. and Mrs. Rossi received in the month of
February salaries of 1,100 and 1,200 euros. For rent they paid
paid 700 euros; for alimony and basic expenses
1200 euros; to each of the three children they granted pocket money
of 30 euros weekly. In addition, they both smoke,
per day, half a pack of cigarettes, the cost of which is
5 euros. Write the arithmetic expression expressing how much
remains for the Rossi family at the end of the month and determine whether the
balance is in surplus or deficit.
Change the answer assuming that Mr. and Mrs. Rossi
are nonsmokers?

R: In deficit by 100 euros, in surplus by 40 euros.

> **My attempt**: Easily we have:

$$1100+1200-700-1200-360=40\, €$$

The value of 40 euros I can find it easily. I cannot find the passive of 100 euros. The problem is: **In addition, they both smoke,
per day, half a pack of cigarettes, the cost of which is
5 euros**. If half a pack of cigarettes is 5 euros, since they are both smokers the total daily expenditure is 10 euros which in one month is 300 euros. In negative I should have 260 euros and not 100 euros. I probably did not understand this last aspect well.

Comment: The question as phrased is ambiguous. The 5 euros might be per person, or for the two of them. There is no way to tell without more information. I suggest you pick one interpretation, state it carefully, and answer the question using it. Or answer it both ways, making clear which is which.

Answer (score 0):

The solution could be this. If I considered a package that costs five euros divided by two comes $2.5$ euros. If I multiplied this amount by $28$ I get a total of $70$ euros per person. If $70$ I multiply it by two (since two are smokers) I get $140$ euros.

We have hence,
$$1100+1200-700-1200-360=\color{red}{40}\,-140=-100 €$$